# Turn into the passive voice: English people still keep princess Diana in mind

Tags: passive-voice

Turn the sentence into the passive voice:
English people still keep princess Diana in mind

My try:
Princess diana still be kept in mind by English people.

Is it correct?

Comment: No, this is not correct.  "Princess Diana is still kept in mind by the English people", but even that is not very good English.  In any case this question is likely to be closed as a duplicate since there are many other questions that teach how to form the passive voice.

Comment: Thank you very much.   But! The verb "to still" doesn't a madel verb ??

Comment: "Still" is just an adverb that modifies the verb "to keep in mind".

Answer (score 1):

As **Andrew** commented there are many questions concerning how to form the *passive voice*, however, the right way to say what you want is:

- "Princess Diana is still kept in mind by the English people"

When you form the passive voice for the verb **"keep"** you change it to **"kept"**, here's the ["**PASSIVE VOICE TO ACTIVE VOICE TABLE**"](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/passive-voice-active-voice/) for the verb **"to keep"**.